# Should I take $g$ as positive or negative when calculating forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, vectors, conventions

This is a question from the Fundamentals of Physics Textbook.

[image]

My approach regarding this problem is that since that there is no acceleration ($\vec{a} = 0$), the net force ($\sum\vec{F}_{net} = 0$) is equal to zero too.

Drew a FBD for it as well:

[image: FBD]

So, my question is when I'm calculating forces, the signs confuse me very much.
Like for the gravitational acceleration ($g$), is it:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum\vec{F}_x &=  \vec{F} \cos \theta - mg \sin \theta  = 0\\
\vec{F} \cos\theta &= mg \sin \theta  \\
\vec{F} \cos (30) &= (100kg) (-9.8 ms^{-2}) (0.5) \\
\vec{F} &= -565.8 N
\end{align*}
$$

or should I take $g$ as positive, then $\vec{F} = 565.8$ ?
Same for $\sum\vec{F}_y$, do I take $g$ as positive or negative?

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum \vec{F}_y &= F_N -mg \cos \theta - \vec{F} \sin \theta = 0 \\
F_N &= mg \cos\theta + \vec{F} \sin \theta 
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of the forces associated with gravity all depend on the coordinate frame you decide to use. Basically, you should *choose* which direction will be positive and which will be negative. Once you choose you should be consistent through-out your entire calculation. Generally it makes sense to choose up to be positive, which looks like what you're doing here.

Also you need to be careful to not over-negate your expressions, which is the case in example derivation you have. Don't sub in $g = -9.8$ if you've already used a minus sign to indicate the force moves in the 'down' direction.

Just think of the sign of force overall, not the particular constant $g$. Keep $g$ positive and just make sure the force overall (e.g. $mg\sin(\theta)$) has the right sign in your coordinates.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot :D